# R dplyr::Filter dataframe by group and numeric vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have dataframe `df1` containing data and groups, and `df2` which stores the same groups, and one value per group.

I want to filter rows of `df1` by `df2` where `lag` by group is higher than indicated value.

Dummy example:

```
  # identify the first year of disturbance by lag by group
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(1:4, 1:4),
                 mort = c(5,16,40,4,5,6,10,108),
                 distance = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4)) 


df2 = data.frame(distance = c("a", "b"),
                       my.median = c(12,1))
```

Now calculate the lag between values (creates new column) and filter `df1` based on column values of `df2`:

```
# calculate lag between years
df1 %>% 
  group_by(distance) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(yearLag  = mort - lag(mort, default = 0)) %>% 
  filter(yearLag > df2$my.median)  ##
```

This however does not produce expected results:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   distance [2]
   year  mort distance yearLag
  <int> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1     2    16 a             11
2     3    40 a             24
3     4   108 b             98
```

Instead, I expect to get:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   distance [2]
   year  mort distance yearLag
  <int> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1     3    40 a             24
2     1     5 b              5
3     3    10 b              4
```

**The `filter` works great while applied to single value, but how to adapt it to vector, and especially vector of groups** (as the order of elements can potentially change?)

Comment: Why is the row with mort = 108 in group b not selected?

Comment: as you pointed out, filtering as you do will not handle the row.median from df2 in row-wise manner, instead only the first value (12) is used. You should therefore go by Aron's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(distance) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(yearLag  = mort - lag(mort, default = 0)) %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>%
  filter(yearLag > my.median)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   distance [2]
   year  mort distance yearLag my.median
  <int> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     3    40 a             24        12
2     1     5 b              5         1
3     3    10 b              4         1
4     4   108 b             98         1
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
#creatae data.tables 
setDT(df1);setDT(df2)
#create yearLag variable
df1[, yearLag := mort - shift( mort, type = "lag", fill = 0 ), by = .(distance) ]
#update join and filter wanted rows
df1[ df2, median.value := i.my.median, on = .(distance)][ yearLag > median.value, ][]

#    year mort distance yearLag median.value
# 1:    3   40        a      24           12
# 2:    1    5        b       5            1
# 3:    3   10        b       4            1
# 4:    4  108        b      98            1
```

Answer (score 1):

Came to the same conclusion. You should left_join the data frames.

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="distance") %>% 
  group_by(distance) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(yearLag  = mort - lag(mort, default = 0)) %>% 
  filter(yearLag > my.median)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   distance [2]
   year  mort distance my.median yearLag
  <int> <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1     3    40 a               12      24
2     1     5 b                1       5
3     3    10 b                1       4
4     4   108 b                1      98
```